# How to optimize Prime Number generator in java?

Tags: java, optimization, java-7

I was doing some question on SPOJ and it is called prime number generator.

My code is working fine on my local machine but on SPOJ i'm getting error of time limit exceeded .

Can someone please tell me how can i make this program and programs of similar kinds with have a lot of nested loop run more efficiently?

```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.lang.*;
  import java.math.*;

  class Main {
     public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = obj.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
           int m = obj.nextInt();
           int n = obj.nextInt();

           for(int x = m; x <= n; x++) {
              boolean flag = true;
              int count = 0;
              for(int j = 2; j < Math.pow(n,0.5) ; j++) {
                 if(x == 1 || x == 2) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                 }
                 if(x % j == 0 && x != j) {
                    flag = false;
                    break;
              }
           }
           if(flag) {
              System.out.println(x);
           }
        }
        System.out.println();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Do you mena [SPOJ.com - Problem PRIME1](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/)?

Comment: yeas i mean that only!

Answer (score 1):

- Calling `Math.pow(n,0.5)` every time in the loop should be slow, so it should be called once before each loop and the return value should be saved.
- You need to divide the values only by *prime numbers* which are equals to or less than `sqrt(n)`.
- Use something like Sieve of Eratosthenes. Instead of judging each number indivisually, remove multiples of primes from the number list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example that's very fast (code is complete so you can test it yourself).

It reduces the number of loops involved by ignoring all even numbers, and testing if number is prime by dividing by the other primes discovered so far

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PrimeGen
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // Max number to search to (hardcoded for example).
        int max = 100;

        // List of primes discovered so far.
        // We'll start it off as [2].
        // We testing if a number is prime we just have to test if it's
        // divisible by the other primes we have discovered so far.
        List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        primes.add(2);

        // Test all odd numbers up to max (evens are not prime).
        for( int i = 3; i < max; i = i + 2 )
        {
            boolean isPrime = true;

            for( int j : primes )
            {
                if( i % j == 0 )
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
            }

            if( isPrime )
            {
                primes.add( i );
            }
        }

        // Print results.
        for( Integer i : primes )
        {
            System.out.print( i + ", " );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Very fast" is an exaggeration.  The Sieve of Eratosthenes is much faster - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_and_variants  ... and there are more advanced algorithms that are faster still.

Comment: @Stephen C Quite right, it's not "very" fast. For truly fast code you'd need to use a more sophisticated algorithm implemented in a language like C or Fortran. The purpose of my example was to get the OP to think about how to reduce the computational complexity of the problem.

Comment: Erm so what is the computational complexity of your code then?  Hint: treating 2 as a special case doesn't alter the complexity.  Also, note that I'm not talking about other (supposedly) faster languages.  I'm talking about algorithms *implemented in Java*.